# RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent listener not getting called

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigClientApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
class ApplicationEventListener implements ApplicationListener<EnvironmentChangeEvent> {
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentChangeEvent event) {
        System.out.println("event listener");
    }
}

@Component
class RefreshEventListener implements ApplicationListener<RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(final RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {
        System.out.println("refresh scope refresh event");
    }

}
}

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("person")
@RefreshScope
public class PersonConfiguration {
    public String name;
//getter and setter for name

}
```

Trying to test if onApplicationEvent is called on RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent listener.

Updated config in git but RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent listener is not getting called. But the EnvironmentChangeEvent listener is called though.

Tried calling `/actuator/refresh`, even here RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent listener is not called, but the EnvironmentChangeEvent listener got called.

This is how i have config in git

```
person:
    name: first last
```

Updated config multiple times and every time only EnvironmentChangeEvent is being called.

What should i change here to have RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent listener called.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into a similar issue with the following class not working properly:

```
    @Slf4j
    @Configuration
    public class RefreshEventListener {

        @EventListener(RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent.class)
        public void onRefresh(RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent event) {
            log.info("Refresh detected")       
        }
    }
```

Could not figure out why it wasn't working until I noticed in the logs that spring was overriding that bean.

2018-10-25 16:03:44.146  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'refreshEventListener' with a different definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [x.x.x.RefreshEventListener]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in URL [jar:file:/app.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/x/x/x/RefreshEventListener.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.RefreshAutoConfiguration; factoryMethodName=refreshEventListener; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.class]]

RefreshEventListener bean is already defined here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/spring-cloud-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.java

I changed the class name to something other than 'RefreshEventListener' and it worked as expected.